# How can I implement Amazon Product Advertising API with a Firebase web app?

Tags: firebase, amazon-product-api

I set up a very simple web app that connects to a Firebase database and facilitates finding the right size among men's pant brands.

I would like the results to link to Amazon using their product advertising API.

The code snippets and solutions I've found are all server-side solutions.

Can I run server side code somehow with a free firebase account?

What would be my best solution?

Comment: Firebase does currently not have an option to run your code on our servers. Recommending a place to run your own scripts is off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you Frank! Would I be able to leverage another baas or paas in conjunction with Firebase? I don't understand how it is off topic. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use Firebase with another backend. Many developers run custom node scripts (or Java processes) to handle tasks that require rights or an infrastructure that you cannot run in a client app/browser. I recommend you select one of those backends, try to get it working and let us know if you get stuck somewhere.